# Multiple DropDownLists from Dictionary (KVP) in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to dynamically create multiple dropdownlists (ASP.Net MVC project) for a user to map columns for importing data from a CSV file. I get the list of columns from the CSV file, and place them in a `SelectList`. These are the SourceColumns from which the user chooses for each destination.

If I hard-code the destination indexes, it works fine. What I mean by this is, if I add an integer property for every destination index.

However, I need to create this dynamically, so I added a Dictionary to my model to hold the destination names and the selected source indexes. The destinations are just key value pairs (`IDictionary<string key, int? value>`) where `value` is the index of the source column.

However, with the dictionary I cannot work out how to get the values back to my controller. They keys come back with null values. Maybe this is not possible with the Html helpers, but any suggestions welcome.

### Model

```
public class ProductionImportModel 
{
    public IDictionary<string, int ?> ColumnIndices { get; set; } 
    // plus other properties
}
```

### Controller

```
model.ColumnIndices.Add("Line", null);
```

### View

```
@foreach (var kvp in @Model.ColumnIndices)
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Model.ColumnIndices[" + @kvp.Key + "].Key", (SelectList)ViewBag.SourceColumns, String.Empty, null)
}
```

### Resulting HTML

```
<select id="Model_ColumnIndices_Line__Key" name="Model.ColumnIndices[Line].Key">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">Col1</option>
    <option value="1">Col2</option>
    <option value="2">Col3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a minor change to my view. I was not providing the correct information for the model binder. I used the DropDownList**For**() helper instead of DropDownList().

### Revised View

```
@foreach (var kvp in @Model.ColumnIndices)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => @Model.ColumnIndices[@kvp.Key], (SelectList)ViewBag.SourceColumns, String.Empty, null)
}
```

This meant that the resulting HTML looked like this

```
<select id="ColumnIndices_Line_" name="ColumnIndices[Line]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">Col1</option>
    <option value="1">Col2</option>
    <option value="2">Col3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Next problem is how to do this with a class as a value instead of the nullable int.